# Idiomatic way of using Functor/Applicative/Monad constructs in ST in Idris

Tags: monads, idris

I tried using `when : Applicative f => Bool -> Lazy (f ()) -> f ()` inside a `ST` do block:

```
loop : (ConsoleIO m, Draw m) =>
       (draw : Var) ->
       (state : GameState) ->
       ST m () [draw ::: SDraw {m}]
loop draw state = with ST do

  print (f state) -- works

  when True (print (f state)) -- error

  ?what
```

which is an error because `ST` is not an applicative apparently, it merely supports `do` syntax.

I assume that there are other useful functor/applicative/monad functions that are also not supported because of this.

Is there some idiomatic solution for this lack?